# Node Express setting cookies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I may be misunderstanding here.

I have a node server running at `localhost:3000`, and a React app running at `localhost:8080`.

The React app is making a `get` request to the node server - my server code for this looks like:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    let user_token = req.cookies['house_user']; // always empty

    if (user_token) {
        // if the token exists, great!
    } else {
        crypto.randomBytes(24, function(err, buffer) {
            let token = buffer.toString('hex');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
            res.cookie('house_user', token, {maxAge: 9000000000, httpOnly: true, secure: false });
            res.send(token);
        });
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

I'm trying to set the `house_user` token, so that I can later keep track of requests from users.

However, the token is not being set on the user (request from `localhost:8080`) - the `house_user` token is always empty (in fact, `req.cookies` is entirely empty). Do I need to do something else?

Comment: `res.cookie...()` is all you need to do so remove the `res.append()`.  `secure:true` will allow the cookie to only work with `https`.  Is the request running on `https`?

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right - my bad; too much sifting through Stack posts and trying multiple solutions :')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried the code below (and it worked). As a reminder, you can just paste this in myNodeTest.js, then run `node myNodeTest.js` and visit http://localhost:3003. If it does work, then it probably means you're having CORS issues.

**[EDIT] withCredentials:true should do the trick with axios.**

```
axios.get('localhost:3000', {withCredentials: true}).then(function (res) { console.log(res) })
```

```
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const crypto = require('crypto');

const port = 3003

app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    let user_token = req.cookies['house_user']; // always empty

    if (user_token) {
        // if the token exists, great!
    } else {
        crypto.randomBytes(24, function(err, buffer) {
            let token = buffer.toString('hex');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
            res.cookie('house_user', token, {maxAge: 9000000000, httpOnly: true, secure: true });
            res.append('Set-Cookie', 'house_user=' + token + ';');
            res.send(token);
        });
    }
});

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.send('Hello from Express!')
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Hey :) - I had required cookie-parser (updated my post to show now) - unfortunately, I still receive no cookies from req.cookies in subsequent requests.

Comment: Have you tried the code I posted, just with a simple `node myNodeTest.js` and visited localhost:3003? I got your cookie ;)

Comment: This is where I think I may be misunderstanding - my goal is to have the cookie set on the client (i.e. my React app running at localhost:8080) which is making a get request to the Node server. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Sure, I know, but if it works like I mentioned, we get one step further knowing it's probably about CORS. Are you using SSR like Next.js?

Comment: I don't think so - I'm using React with Axiom to make a request like: axios.get('http://localhost:3000').then(function (res) { console.log(res) })

Comment: I'll edit step by step based on your comments. The problem does come from Axios, 99% sure about it.

Comment: Asten - adding withCredentials: true worked! Thank you so much :D

Comment: @ConnorCartwright you're welcome, after you told me about Axios I was sure the problem lied there ;) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Making my comment into an answer since it seemed to have solved your problem.

Since you are running on `http`, not `https`, you need to remove the `secure: true` from the cookie as that will make the cookie only be sent over an `https` connection which will keep the browser from sending it back to you over your `http` connection.

Also, remove the `res.append(...)` as `res.cookie()` is all that is needed.

Comment: Re the comments on Asten's answer, the issue still persists but may just be me trying to do something that is not possible.

Comment: @ConnorCartwright - Your axios request should be: `axios.get('http://localhost:3000').then(...).catch(...)` with the protocol in the URL.